# Of the subjects in our experiment, 50% are/were male

Tags: tenses

I'm writing a report and need to decide whether to use present or past tense:

Of the subjects in our experiment, 50% `are/were` male, 50% `have/had` at least a college degree, 90% `are/were` employed...

According to the 2010 US Census, 49% of the population `are/were` male, and 27% `have/had` at least a college degree, 91% `are/were` employed...

Should the words in gray be in present tense or past tense? Or is it immaterial as long as I'm consistent? (Note: statistics are made up)

Comment: Is the experiment ongoing, or has it completed? Use the appropriate tense.

Comment: It's completed. Since the US Census is also complete, does that mean everything should be in past tense?

Comment: I'm not @Davo, but I would say yes but with the exception of the current year's census. E.g. even though the 2017 census itself may be completed, its results will be considered the _current_ results for the entirety of 2017.

Comment: If the rest of the description  of the experiment is in the past tense, then so should this be.  In particular, "27% had at least a college degree": that is the number back when the experiment was done, not taking into account any participants who may have obtained a degree since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick way to answer this question is to look at what other papers in your field do. But, most likely, they will use the past tense.

My copy of the *Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association* (6th ed.) says:

> **Select tense carefully.** Use the past tense to express an action or a condition that occurred at a specific, definite time in the past, as when discussing another researcher's work and *when reporting your results*.

(Bold in original; italics are mine).

Secondly, naturally, some of these states can change. While no one is likely to change what degrees they have, it is conceivable that some of your subjects will have lost their job, died, or changed their gender identity between collection and publication.

Comment: Use the present tense only if discussing the current state of the experimental subjects; use the past tense in the report that gives the results of the experiment.